# Javafx added to a current java module

Tags: java, javafx

I have a module that was created in java in inteilij under the build system of Maven. I have package set up with classes with them, along with a main class. I need to set up a javafx form, but when I goto like i'm going to add a class it does not have javafx on the list of options. How do I add it to the list or how do I get the form? this is for a class and of course the video show it there on his but it's not on mine.

I need to set up a javafx form, but when I goto like i'm going to add a class it does not have javafx on the list of options. How do I add it to the list or how do I get the form?

Comment: I find it easiest to start a new project in IntelliJ using the bundled JavaFX template.